# how to remove hint when someone inputs in text input - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have a this text input

```
<input id="searchInput" type="text" value="Search Here" />
```

I want to remove the value of the input i.e. 'Search Here' as someone enters something ...
How to do this in jQuery or in javascript ?

Comment: why can't you use placeholder instead of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use placeholder text

```
<input id="searchInput" type="text" placeholder="Search Here" />
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute

Comment: Please _don't_ link to http://www.w3fools.com, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120025/will-i-be-downvoted-for-giving-a-w3schools-link. Here's the official resource: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute

Comment: And if you're looking for a placeholder "polyfill" in case you'd have to make this compatible with Microsoft Internet Explorer, you can check this jQuery plugin https://github.com/dciccale/placeholder-enhanced

Comment: Oh... I didn't know that it is this much simple... And I wasted one hour to make it work like this in javascript...   :)

Answer (score 0):

If the browser provides HTML5 capabilities you could simply use the [`placeholder`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute) attribute.

However, if the user agent doesn't provide HTML5 capabilities you can use `onfocus` and `onblur`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Placeholder for your code.

```
<input id="searchInput" type="text" placeholder="Search Here" />
```

Here's a workind [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FD4RD/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you say jQuery, [jquery-watermark](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/) is a good plugin.

It will add a watermark regardless of the browser capabilities.

It will use a [placeholder](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute) if the browser supports it, and fallback to creating dom elements on browsers that don't

```
$('#searchInput').watermark('Search Here');
```